# how to retrieve data from sqlite to ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm unable to find a way to retrieve data from SQLite database to ListView once I save it, yup there are lots of ways out there, but I want to do it my way because I'm new to SQLite.

So, If anyone knows it here please help me out.

Here's the error

[image: Error Log]

So, here's what I've done.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
    byte[] imagebyte;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "moderncampus", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table hodtable(firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, email EMAIL)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists hodtable");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insert(String name, String last, String email){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("firstname", name);
        contentValues.put("lastname", last);
        contentValues.put("email", email);

        long ins = db.insert("hodtable", null, contentValues);
        if (ins == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getdetails(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select firstname, lastname, email from hodtable", null);

        return cursor;
    }

}
```

HodListAdapter.java  - Custom ListView Adapter

```
public class HodListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<String> title, title2;
    private final ArrayList<String> subtitle;

    public HodListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> title, ArrayList<String> title2, ArrayList<String> subtitle/*, Integer[] imgid*/){
        super(context, R.layout.hod_list, title);

        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.title2 = title2;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
        final viewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        if (view == null){
            inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hod_list, null, true);

            holder = new viewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.last = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title2);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (viewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(title.get(position));
        holder.last.setText(title2.get(position));
        holder.email.setText(subtitle.get(position));

        return view;
    }

    public class viewHolder{
        TextView name;
        TextView last;
        TextView email;
    }

}
```

CollegeAdmin.java - Activity

```
public class CollegeAdmin extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    ArrayList<String> listitem;

    FloatingActionButton fabplus, fabdept;
    Animation fabOpen, fabClose, fabRC, fabRAC;

    private ListView list;

    ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> subtitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> title2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            boolean isOpen = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_college_admin);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Admin");

        fabplus = findViewById(R.id.fab_plus);
        fabdept = findViewById(R.id.fab_department);

        fabOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
        fabClose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close);
        fabRC = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_clockwise);
        fabRAC = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_anticlock);

        fabplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isOpen){
                    fabdept.startAnimation(fabClose);
                    fabplus.startAnimation(fabRAC);
                    fabdept.setClickable(false);
                    isOpen = false;
                } else {
                    fabdept.startAnimation(fabOpen);
                    fabplus.startAnimation(fabRC);
                    fabdept.setClickable(true);
                    isOpen = true;
                }
            }
        });

        listitem = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        viewData();
        super.onPostResume();
    }

    private void viewData() {
        sqLiteDatabase = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM hodtable", null);
        title.clear();
        title2.clear();
        subtitle.clear();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Entries", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    title.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstname")));
                    subtitle.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastname")));
                    title2.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            HodListAdapter adapter = new HodListAdapter(this, title, title2, subtitle);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to instantiate your `DatabaseHelper` in `CollegeAdmin`; e.g., `db = new DatabaseHelper(this);`

Comment: I did as you said but it still shows same. [Mike M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m)

Comment: Exactly where and how did you do it? That is, what is the exact line of code you used, and where did you put it? Btw, it's @MikeM. to notify me. The link won't do it.

Comment: I've update the query you can check there @MikeM.

Comment: That's a different error. You forgot to assign `list`; e.g., `list = findViewById(R.id.whatever);`. Please have a read through the linked duplicate. It'll help you to understand what a `NullPointerException` means, and how to fix it.

Comment: never mind I figured it out, thank you all, yup that was the missing part @MikeM.

Comment: hey @MikeM. by any chance do you know same question but with image retrieval, if you know then please provide a link, it'll be really helpful

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Images in the `ListView`? If so, where are they coming from?

Comment: I've already wrote a code to upload image on sqlite database and all I want to do now is to retrieve it from there @MikeM.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. You saved an image link in the database? Or you saved a byte array to the database? Or something else?

Comment: took bitmap of image, then converted to byte, and then uploaded the image to sqlite @MikeM.

Comment: Well, you generally don't want to save images in a database, but you'll use the `Cursor#getBlob()` method to get your `byte[]` back. Then you could use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`, if you want simple, built-in stuff, but that can cause issues, especially in a `ListView`, where you'll have a bunch of images loaded at once. The usual recommendation is to use an image loading library like Glide or Picasso. There are thousands of examples out there for each.